# Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'cookie-es' | After Nuxt 3 build in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, nuxtjs3, windows-explorer, nuxt3

## The issue

The Nuxt 3 build exports module **"cookie-es" as a reference**, symbolic link or how it's called in Win. The reference will be empty after copying.

## I propose a question

How do I **tell Nuxt to export a module as a standard directory** (if possible), or in the worse case, how do I copy a file in Windows droping references and making real files of them instead?

## The problem showcase

how "node_modules" looks like **after build** (path....output\server\node_modules)
[node_module cookie-es outside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QklyG.png)

how "node_modules" looks like **after build** (path....output\server\node_modules)
[node_module cookie-es inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4wXx.png)

how "node_modules" looks like **after copied** (otherPath....output\server\node_modules)
[node_module cookie-es outside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUMWk.png)

how "node_modules" looks like **after copied** (otherPath....output\server\node_modules)
[node_module cookie-es inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EE7aJ.png)

where is it referencing files from? From "node_modules/.nitro"
[node_module .nitro inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8tdX.png)

In plain words only, content of a directory is lost after copying, due to a loss of a reference I quess.

## Variables

OS: Windows 10
Nuxt: ^3.4.3

## What I tried

I have tried disabling symlinks in vite config (inside nuxt.config)

```
vite: {
    resolve: {
        preserveSymlinks: false
    }
}
```

AND

I have tried to manualy copy the files from the **"build modules"** into the lost gaps in **"copied modules"**. **It works but its not a possibility** to manually find the problem ones and copy them every time.

## Solution

I have solved the issue by auto-copying file (inside package.json)

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "postbuild": "robocopy /e /j \".output/server/node_modules\" 
        \".output/server/node_modules_copy\" & rd /s /q 
        \".output/server/node_modules\" & robocopy /e /j 
        \".output/server/node_modules_copy\" \".output/server/node_modules\" 
        & rd /s /q \".output/server/node_modules_copy\""
}
```

It copies modules without symbolic links into a new directory and then copies it back as node_modules.

Please feel free to post a better solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In general there are many packages that will fail to work as they are hopelessly dependent traditional `node_modules` directory structure, so anything that goes beyond the basic traditional spec of NPM will break some packages because the authors didn't take a modern adaptive approach when building their lib.

> You haven't specified how you instigated your project, I will assume you used one of the following modern package managers that this type of issue is typically caused by:

## PNPM

If you used `pnpm` to instigate your project then issues around symbolic linking can arise, there are unfortunately many packages that wont work with `pnpm`.

You might try the folloing configutation options:

https://pnpm.io/blog/2020/10/17/node-modules-configuration-options-with-pnpm#plugnplay-the-strictest-configuration

```
node-linker=pnp
symlink=false
```

## YARN 3

If you used `yarn` you can have a similar issue with certain packages not working because specifically because of the lack of a `node_modules` directory in a project root, in the case of yarn you can fix package import issues using the node linker config in a `.yarnrc.yml` file in your project root.

```
nodeLinker: node-modules
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your input. **For the clarification I'm using reqular npm**. Have checked the link you included about pnpm config and tried setting both options for npm.

Comment: Doesn't let me edit anymore.

Took no effect on the actual build from Nuxt (it generates new package.json and builds a separate node_modules inside of "dist" folder) still generating junction. But I'm not sure about that.  
  
Also I really don't know what Nuxt really does inside of "nuxt build". So I believe simply removing symlink/junction after build is more afordable solution.